# No horizontal scrolling in Grails scaffolded views

Tags: java, grails, grails-3.0, grails3

I have a table with relatively long values in some columns and have dynamic scaffolding turned on for it in my Grails application (I'm using Grails 3.3.8). Thus, on some screen resolutions, they don't fit on the screen and the rightmost columns end up outside of the screen - thing is, the horizontal scrolling bar does not appear then and so the user doesn't even know they're there. The only way to bring them back in is to zoom out - you can't scroll with either the bar (cause it's not there) or the mouse wheel; arrows aren't working either.

How can I fix this so that the horizontal scrolling bar appears like on a "regular" webpage on which content exceeds the size of the screen?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? Include that in your question. That would be helpful.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore - oh, sure! I'm using 3.3.8, edited that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured this out! So the trick is to edit the `assets/stylesheets/main.css` file in the app folder, specifically this bit:

```
body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    color: #333333;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* <<<< */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #424649;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #424649;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.3em #424649;
}
```

We edit the `overflow-x` from `hidden` to `auto` and voila! :)